# MS turning off Basic Authentication for Exchange Online in 2020

Tags: exchange-basicauth

We are wondering how best to allow users (managed via MDM ideally - we use IBM MaaS360) to access their corporate email on corporate devices only. Currently we quarantine devices that connect to Exchange Online which stops user installing or accessing corporate email on non company devices.

So how best to manage this big change to authentication?

Tested by disabling basic authentication on my own account.  This rendered EAS unusable.

Comment: Hi Gary,

This change is related to the applications using BasicAuth to connect to Exchange Online. If your users are already on apps that make use of Modern Auth (Outlook Mobile, latest versions of Apple Mail) they will not see an impact.

Are you enforcing the use of specific apps within your organization? If yes, you will need to update the app to support OAuth.

Comment: Yes i know. Issue is that we are using EAS and will continue to for the foreseeable.  We are not going to deploy apps at present.

Comment: Wouldn't IBM be the party responsible for updating their app to use OAuth 2.0 or similar if that's how you connect to Exchange Online?

Comment: Yes they are.  They support it for a certain policy config but not for all users currently.